# Haskell - eliminate prime numbers from a list

Tags: haskell, syntax

I want to write a function wp (without primes) which removes all the primes from a list
of numbers. Thus, wp [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] = [1, 4, 6].

I tried coding it like this:

```
wp :: [Int] -> [Int]
prime :: Int -> Bool

prime n = if f n > 0 then False else True
   where f n = foldl (\acc x -> if n `mod` x == 0 then acc = acc + 1 else acc = acc + 0) 0 [2..n-1]
wp xs = filter (not.prime) xs
```

But when compiling it, I get the "parse error on input =" error but I can't find my syntax error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the use of `acc = acc + x`. You just need to write it as `acc + 1` or `acc + 0` (or just `acc` really) instead. Also, I would recommend writing the function signature on top of the function definition, rather than a C-style list at the top.

Finally, I should note that `wp` will not include 1 in the result, so you will have to manually include it.

```
prime :: Int -> Bool
prime n = if f n > 0 then False else True
     where f n = foldl (\acc x -> if n `mod` x == 0 then acc + 1 else acc) 0 [2..n-1]

wp :: [Int] -> [Int]
wp xs = 1 : filter (not.prime) xs
```